Простой вопрос о принципе работы apscheduler
Если я для начала добавляю job в шедулер, после чего его запускаю методом start, то если во время того как он отрабатывает я создам ещё один job нужно ли будет перезапускать шедулер или заного вызвать start?
Вот пример:
scheduler: AsyncIOScheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(timezone="Europe/Moscow")

# ЭТО МОЖЕТ ВЫЗВАТЬСЯ ХЕНДЛЕРОМ В БОТЕ
async def new_task(event: types.TelegramObject):
    scheduler.add_job(first_send_interval, trigger='date',
                      id=f'{event.from_user.id}first',
                      run_date=datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1.5),
                      kwargs={'event': event})
    scheduler.add_job(second_send_interval, trigger='date',
                      id=f'{event.from_user.id}second',
                      run_date=datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=7),
                      kwargs={'event': event})
    scheduler.add_job(third_send_interval, trigger='date',
                      id=f'{event.from_user.id}third',
                      run_date=datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=19),
                      kwargs={'event': event})

# А ВОТ ЭТО ТОЧНО ОТРАБОТАЕТ ЕДИНОЖДЫ ПРИ СТАРТЕ
scheduler.add_job(every_day, trigger='cron', id='id',
                  hour=4, start_date=datetime.now())

# ШЕДУЛЕР СТАРТОНЁТ В МЕЙН ФАЙЛЕ БОТА


Нет, перезапускать не нужно

Такие детали нужно искать в документации:

Adding jobs
[...]
You can schedule jobs on the scheduler at any time. If the scheduler is not yet running when the job is added, the job will be scheduled tentatively and its first run time will only be computed when the scheduler starts.

Вкратце: вы можете добавлять задачи в любое время - и до старта шедулера и после.
